# Reload/Refresh Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to reload all the grid (not only the data).

I'm trying with:

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

but `read()` reloads only the data and `refresh()` is not working. When a user clicks on the button, I need to recreate all the table with new columns (I don't know how many columns or what columns, the server process it).

Users can change the columns that they see with a html checkbox. The first time the table charges correctly but if the user change the checkbox value the columns don't change. If deselect an option the column is empty and if the user adds an option, the new column don't appear.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should destroy and recreate the grid to change the columns.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: yourURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').destroy();
        $('#Grid').empty(); //necessary to remove the old html

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: result,
                schema: {
                    data: "d"
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The result of your ajax should be something like:

```
var result = { 'd': [
    { description: "Description 1", number: 30, price: 3.5 },
    { description: "Description 2", number: 33, price: 4 },
    { description: "Description 3", number: 40, price: 4.5 }
]}
```

Comment: If I have an ajax petition for the data can I do that? I don't know the number or name of columns. I try with remove and empty but I don't know how to recreate the grid with ajax. All examples that I found are similar that yours  but I don't know how to use it in my code (is the first time I use telerik)

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you could deal with an ajax call.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try it! c:

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to attempt to reselect the last record? This function below uses the same method you described above and has been working for ages. What you posted above should work. What makes you say it is not working?

```
function refreshGrid(gridID) {
    var grid = $('#' + gridID).data('kendoGrid');
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    grid.dataSource.read();
    grid.refresh();
    if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.uid != null) {
        var row = grid.tbody.find('tr[data-uid="' + selectedItem.uid + '"]');
        row.addClass("k-state-selected");
        grid.select(row);
        grid.select(grid.table.find('tr').first());
    }
}
```

Comment: Users can change the columns that they see with a html checkbox.
The first time the table charges correctly but if the user change the checkbox value the columns don't change. If deselect an option the column is empty and if the user adds an option, the new column don't appear

(sorry for the my bad english...)

Comment: I think you should explore the [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions) method, you might be able to get it to do what you need.

Comment: I added your comment above to your question as it adds a little more info. This will not preserve the column selection as the grid will be redrawn with the default config. The answer may lie in the comment above.

Comment: Joe Glover, I'll prove it, thanks. 

RossBush, That's true, thanks!

Comment: The refresh method repaints the grid using the current data source data. To refresh the data source use read method:

    grid.dataSource.read();

Comment: read method only repaints the data, I need to repaint all the grid (columns headers and data)

Answer (score 0):

k-rebind="gridOptions"

This event will rebind the grid whenever gridOptions are changed.